# Differential Equation Absolute Value

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I must solve $\frac{dy}{dt} = y(1-y)$. I work through this using partial fractions and obtain |$\frac{y}{1-y}|$ $=$ $Ae^t$.

I am confused what to do with the absolute values. Would I have two separate general solutions being $\frac{y}{1-y}$ $=$ $Ae^t$ and $\frac{-y}{1-y}$ $=$ $Ae^t$?

Comment: You have $\pm$ in your constant $A$

Comment: @EgorIvanov Okay so the final answer is $\frac{y}{1-y} = +- Ae^t$? Isn't that the same as what I wrote?

Comment: You don't need to write $\pm$, because if $A$ is any real number, then $\pm A$ is also any real number, so the answer is $\frac{y}{1-y} = A \exp\{t\}$

Comment: Okay so I just drop the absolute values and obtain that. So I can go from |$\frac{y}{1-y}$| $=$ $Ae^t$ straight to $\frac{y}{1-y}$ $=$ $Ae^t$ ?

Comment: Formally you can write smth like: $\left|\frac{y}{1-y}\right| = A\exp t\Rightarrow \frac{y}{1-y}=\pm A\exp t\Rightarrow \frac{y}{1-y} = B\exp t$

Comment: @EgorIvanov Thank you so much.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303144/help-with-ode-cannot-get-to-computed-solution-possible-problem-with-absolute

Answer (score 0):

Your question is

Solve: $\frac{dy}{dt}=y(1-y)$.

$\implies \frac{1}{y(1-y)}dy=dt$

$\implies$ $\int \frac{1}{y(1-y)}dy=\int dt +C$

$\implies \int \frac{y+(1-y)}{y(1-y)}dy=\int dt +C$

$\implies \int \frac{y}{y(1-y)}dy+\int \frac{(1-y)}{y(1-y)}dy=\int dt +C$

$\implies \int \frac{1}{(1-y)}dy +\int \frac{1}{y}dy=\int dt +C$

$\implies \ln|1-y|+\ln|y|=t +C$

$\implies \ln|y(1-y)|=t +C$

Comment: Modulus function will work only when the condition $t(y)=n$ will be given. Here n is a real number.